# Python logging - how do I disable or set different logging level for some modules, using the logger configuration file?

Tags: python, python-logging

I'm reading the logging configuration from a config file:

`logging.config.fileConfig(fname=logConfigFilePath, disable_existing_loggers=False)`.

The logging config is as basic as it can be:

```
[loggers]
keys=root

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=consoleHandler

[handlers]
keys=consoleHandler

[handler_consoleHandler]
class=StreamHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=consoleFormatter
args=(sys.stdout,)

[formatters]
keys=consoleFormatter

[formatter_consoleFormatter]
format=%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(filename)s-%(funcName)s %(message)s
```

I need to set a different logging level (eg. `WARNING`) for some specific modules, like this one:

`DEBUG connectionpool.py-_new_conn Starting new HTTPS connection (1):...`

How can I do this, **NOT programmatically, but using the config file** ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the configuration, you can manipulate the runtime logger through its [qualname](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html#:%7E:text=The%20qualname%20entry%20is%20the%20hierarchical%20channel%20name%20of%20the%20logger%2C%20that%20is%20to%20say%20the%20name%20used%20by%20the%20application%20to%20get%20the%20logger.).

For example let's say your logger is in the module `a.b` and you're using `logging.getLogger(__name__)`.

You'd extend your loggers section to contain the new logger configuration name, and a new section for the logger where you give it the different level, and link it to the runtime logger through the qualname

```
[loggers]
keys=root,changed_logger

[logger_changed_logger]
qualname=a.b
level=DEBUG
;inherit all handlers from parent, do not create any new ones
propagate=1
handlers=
```